# read, search, capture, store in MySQl using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Table1 has got two columns `names` and `details` with `FUll TEXT SEARCH` enabled

```
names | details
----------------------------
Mathew | car,home,insurance,job
levin  | home,business,shop
john   | car,home,insurance
abin   | home,insurance,job
neil   | shop,car,home,tax
yancy  | computer,consultant,engineer
```

First step:

read each name and its `details` in `table1`

Second step:

Search in the table1 with `details` of each `names`

third step:

capture the search result of `names`

fourth step:

Store it into table2 with name in first step and captured `names` in third step.

fianlly table2 look like

```
 name   | names
 -----------------------
 Mathew | john,abin,neil
```

How can I do this in PHP with MySQL?? I want do this for upto 250k approx.

Comment: It is always a bad idea to use combined with comma values instead of having general many-to-many relations implementation.

Comment: I know how to loop through names and get details but then how I search with details?? ah I am confused

Comment: well how that can be done?? I am beginner and only know basics of MySQl

Comment: the one of the first links from google: http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php http://www.tekstenuitleg.net/en/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/many-to-many.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option to break those details out into a child table?  Cuz if you can, then it is trivial.

Assuming they have been broke out, you have:

```
name   detail
-------------
john   car
john   insurance
neil   car
neil   home
...etc...
```

Your desired output is much easier to read than your step-wise explanation, it **looks** like you want, for any given person, all the other people who have at least one detail in common, no?  If so, the query is:

```
-- the strange CASE WHEN eliminates transitive closure
-- where you will get john,bill and bill,john 
select case when t1.name < t2.name then t1.name else t2.name end as name1
     , case when t1.name < t2.name then t2.name else t1.name end as name2
  from childTable t1
  join childtable t2 on t1.detail = t2.detail
                    and t1.name   <>t2.name
 group by case when t1.name < t2.name then t1.name else t2.name end 
        , case when t1.name < t2.name then t2.name else t1.name end 
 order by case when t1.name < t2.name then t1.name else t2.name end 
        , case when t1.name < t2.name then t2.name else t1.name end
```

The ORDER BY is not strictly necessary, but if you run this in a console it makes it easier to inspect the results.

All of those CASE...WHEN statements eliminate the problem of duplicate pairs.  Without them the query will double every answer, you'll get "joe,bill" and "bill,joe" and "suzy,john" and "john,suzy".  Those CASE..WHENs cause them to always have the alphabetically lower name first so they can be collapsed and dupes eliminated.

After that, you can use a Common Table Expression to combine these on the server, or just loop through them in PHP.  The php might look like this:

```
 <?php
 # Assuming rows have been retrieved...
 $matches = array();
 foreach($rows as $row) {
     $matches[$row['name1']][] = $row['name2'];
 }
 foreach($matches as $name1=>$names) {
     echo "$name1 has details in common with ".implode(",",$names);
 }
 ?>
```

One last note.  I don't want to think about trying to do this without first normalizing that list of details :(